# Is there a simple condition to check a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, conditional-statements

I need a SELECT statement of type `IF(expression='', 'Web', expression)`, but the problem is that expression is huge and I don't want to repeat it.

Is there a way to do it using expression only once? I tried combining `IFNULL()` with other nested conditions, but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

The solution may be simple, but I am new to SQL.

EDIT:
I managed to solve it in Bigquery using
`SELECT  IFNULL(NULLIF(expression, ''), 'Web') FROM ...`

Comment: Yes, with varied possibilities depending on your RDBMS, which you haven't [tagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: You might set some variables along the way, but it raises complexity and might get you into some issues as well. When it's TOO complex, you might consider moving your logic to the application that is consuming the result of the query. If you're running sql standalone, you can think of writing a procedure that will contain one ore more queries and basic `if`, `switch` statements, variables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make `expression` be `null` if invalid instead of `''`?

Then you could almost certainly have:

```sql
COALESCE(huge_expression, 'Web')
```

Comment: Thanks Jack! I used IFNULL(NULLIF(expression, ''), 'Web') in Bigquery, wich is equivalent to COALESCE(NULLIF(expression, ''), 'Web') that you suggested

Comment: I work with an Oracle codebase heavily littered with `NVL`, which is Oracle's `IFNULL`, so hadn't seen `IFNULL` before. The difference is that `IFNULL` takes a single maybe-null value and a fallback, while `COALESCE` takes multiple maybe-null values and gives the first not-null value.